# Java LinkedList has no direct access to Node

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm surprised to discover that Java's LinkedList has no direct access to Node. What if I already store somewhere Node's reference and want to use it for unlink, linkAfter, linkBefore... Why to search it again at O(n)?!! These methods are not public!

Comment: LinkedList wraps all the operations on the list and offers you methods to use them. If you need direct access to certain elements without internally iterating the list, maybe an ArrayList would be the better choice?

Comment: You can, however, store an `Iterator` (or `ListIterator`). Which may be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: Implement your own LinkedList. Java only provides standard functions and features,

Comment: How could you store a node reference without using any `Iterator`? It's impossible since `LinkedList` doesn't expose its Nodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The real time efficiency of LinkedList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528087/the-real-time-efficiency-of-linkedlist-in-java)

Comment: I can not use ListIterator for storing random elements in efficient way because it's started from begin/end. Again, I need to perform O(n). What a disappointment that Java bars access to what actually already exists. Of cause, one can overwrite class or use reflection but what a way...

Comment: Regarding recommendation for different structures (like ArrayList of Set) instead: Think about FIFO queue with random unlink functionality

Comment: This reads more like a rant than an actual question.

Comment: Not sure about the above comment about not being able to use an `Iterator`. Regardless of what mechanism you use, you must iterate in `O(n)` to get to your "random node". There is no way to randomly access nodes in any linked list implementation. I don't understand your comment. I agree with @MarkRotteveel, you don't seem to want advice, you want to vent.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Again, "FIFO queue with random unlink functionality". When I add new node I can store it in external map. So, when I "must iterate in O(n)" ?

Comment: When you add your new node how do you add it? How do you get its parent?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I add new node to FIFO and external Map. I can decide to unlink it in the middle of the FIFO

Comment: At that point you have basically lost any benefit you may have had from the linked list - you not only have a linked list (one the slowest data-structures from a memory performance perspective) but also a `Map`. Just use a `LinkedHashMap` - it's also slow and unperformant but at least it's tested and works.

Comment: @BoristheSpider . Thank you, LinkedHashMap is close but still not exactly the same. Restriction on access to list entries, in fact, limits the functionality of the specific case (with Map). But one may wish also LinkedList with direct access to Nodes but with no relation to Map at all.

Answer (score 2):

The nodes in a `LinkedList` are indeed hidden from the clients, so you cannot "store somewhere Node's reference".

Depending on your actual use case, you may roll your own linked list with public nodes or switch to a different collection, like a `HashSet` (for O(1) search and removal of arbitrary elements).

Comment: `linkAfter`, `linkBefore` implies order...

Answer (score 0):

It might be, depending on you application, that you would be better off with a set or a map, in addition to the ArrayList mentioned by @mumpitz.